# Customize Gallery Widget android

Tags: android, android-gallery, android-custom-view

I want to create an `Gallery`-like `View` which are same as `Gallery` widget in android! If I try to use default `Gallery` with `Adapter` which is list of small `Bitmap`, It work nicely! However, there's default focus of `Gallery` (focused `Bitmap` is default on the center of screen), I don't want that focus! I want to make my `View` act as a `Gallery` but doesn't has `default` focus!

In conclusion, I want to create a `Gallery` which focused `Item` can be at any position of `Gallery` and that `Item` doesn't automatically move to center of Screen! How can I do that? Should I `inherit` from `Gallery` widget? Or I should create my own `View`?

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Just in case you are still waiting, the answer is [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html).